# Ionic v1 camera gallery

Tags: ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I’m trying to implement this function in my Ionic v1 app:
after taking a photo, display it as in this image: [mycamerapage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H9IU0.png)

Any idea how I can do this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Install the camera plugin from [here](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera).
2. You will get image URI in `imageData` variable.
3. Now you can easily display the image in your page.